# Firebase Python: How to query for range of children if child values cannot be sorted?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new to Firebase, so forgive me if my question is not well thought out.

I am trying to query for the N-th entry of a database. For example, if I have a database called `'dinosaurs'`, I should be able to query for the 10th entry, or a range of entries, such as 10th to 100th.

In the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries), there are a few ways to query for specific entry or entries like so:

1. Querying for specific matches according to the child:

`ref = db.reference()`

`ref.order_by_child('height').equal_to(25).get()`

or querying for a range of starting and ending index values:

```
ref.order_by_key().start_at('b').end_at(u'b\uf8ff').get()
```

But my database, `discover-db`, has its (first-level) child populated with random alphanumeric characters, followed by second-level children such as `"request", "results", and "timestamp"`.

I am able to query for top/bottom N values, by using the following code:

```
db.reference('discover-db').order_by_key().limit_to_last(N).get()
```

But how do I query for, say, 10th to 100th entries in the database, without the ability to sort the child values using `order_by_child('height')`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The indexing is not enabled in the admin level:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dinosaurs": {
      ".indexOn": ["height", "length"]
    }
  }
}
```

Doing this solved the problem of querying by timestamp/other child of child entries